# Start ACODE or any other text editor from Termux

Tags: android, shell, text-editor, termux

I have a file in my directory named `file.sh`

What I want is to **directly open** this file with any *GUI based Text Editor* of android from a Termux command/script. I prefer ***ACODE*** because of it's simplicity. Any other editor would do the job.

I know that `am start --user 0 -n com.Package.name/MainActivity` would open the app, but I want to pass the file also with it. Is it possible? If possible, then how?

Comment: `termux-open file.sh`? You'd probably need to `chmod 777 <dir>`, <directories to that file> though to give the app access to open that file.

Comment: @Darkman Termux gives only read permission of a file opened by `termux-open`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to get my work done. I opened an **FTP** server in Termux and then *connected my ACODE to the FTP*. Now everything works fine.